# Linux Kernel- task_h_load

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, load-balancing

I'm trying to understand what happens during the `load_balance` function.
I'm checking version 3.14 but I also took a look at version 4.3 since I was told that the mechanism was changed and a bit more clear in this version.

in **v3.14** the call is from [`move_tasks`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c?v=3.14#L4980)

in **v4.3** the call is from [`detach_tasks`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L5702)

from what I see it is the same function but only with a different name.

This function is moving tasks from one queue to another according to the `env->balance` parameter.
What I don't understand is what/how the load is calculated in [`task_h_load`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L5739).

Does anyone know what the load member represent and how it is calculated in the **`task_h_load`** function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[CFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler) holds a tree of "scheduling entities". Each scheduling entity can have its own tree, and so on in a recursive way...
(This is useful, for example, for grouping all the processes of a specific user into one scheduling entity; thus preventing a user that has many tasks from consuming more cpu time than users with fewer processes)

task_h_load - stands for "**task hierarchical load**"

Since a task can be nested in a few trees, then calculating its load is not so simple...

```
static unsigned long task_h_load(struct task_struct *p){
    struct cfs_rq *cfs_rq = task_cfbs_rq(p);
    update_cfs_rq_h_load(cfs_rq);
    return div64_ul(p->se.avg.load_avg * cfs_rq->h_load,
                           cfs_rq_load_avg(cfs_rq) + 1);
}
```

At the beginning `cfs_rq` points to the immediate tree at which p is found in. If we had only two nested trees then calculating the load of p would have been simple:

> task_h_load = task_load_in_its_tree * ( load_of_immediate_tree / 
>   load_of_containing_tree);
>
> (while immediate_tree refers to the tree that contains the task,
>   and containing_tree refers to the tree that contains the tree that contains the task.)

But this is not the case.  Our tree might be a nested tree inside a scheduling entity, which is itself just a leaf in another tree.

So, the first thing we do is to call `update_cfs_rq_h_load(cfs_rq)` which computes the hierarchical load factor for `cfs_rq` and all its ascendants (ancestors):  this function goes up the tree hierarchy all the way to the root, and down from the root to our `cfs_rq` while computing the hierarchical load factor for each tree in the hierarchy.

The computation is done in a similar way:

> cfs_rq_h_load = cfs_rq_load_in_its_tree * (load_of_immediate_tree / 
>   load_of_containing_tree)

So, finally we have the fractional load of `cfs_rq` and all we have to do is to calculate the h_load using the same formula.

> task_h_load = task_load_in_its_tree * (load_of_immediate_tree / 
>   load_of_containing_tree)

Answer (score 16):

Load balancing is invoked if SMP is configured.Linux uses [Completely Fair Scheduler](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-completely-fair-scheduler/)(CFS) to schedule each task so that each one obtain “fair” share of the processor time.. CFS uses concept of [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

[image]

Scheduler records the current time when a task enters into the run queue. While the process waits for processor time, it's “wait” value gets incremented by an amount derived from the total number of tasks currently in the run queue and the process priority. When processor runs this task ,this "wait" value gets decremented.  If this value drops below certain value then scheduler will preempt the task and other task come closer to processor to execute. CFS always try to keep situation ideal by keeping "wait" value zero.

There are two functions in linux `load_balance` and `select_task_rq_fair()` which perform the task of load balance.

In simple word CFS load balance mechanism offload the busy CPU to less busy or ideal one.

`task_h_load` is used to calculate weight of task.

> What I don't understand is what/how the load is calculated in
>   task_h_load.
>   how it is calculated in the task_h_load function?

This weight factor depends on nice value of the process.

```
weighting factor = weight of process with nice value 0 / weight of current task;
```

where ‘[weight](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/sched.h#L276)’ is approximately equivalent to 1024 * (1.25)^(-nice)

For example : 
weight is 820 for nice value 1
weight is 1277 for nice value -1

[task_h_load](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L5893)
For more load-balance methods and basics refer [kernel comment](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c?v=3.14#L4587) 
`task_h_load` use  `update_cfs_rq_h_load` to calculate hierarchical load of run queue for fair time scheduling and which use  cfs_rq_load_avg return average load of runqueue [load_avg](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1192).

Virtual run time is the weighted time a task has run on the CPU. CFS always try to keep [this](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~krj/os/lectures/L12-LinuxSched.pdf) Red-black tree in balance.

[image]

**<--smaller value -----------vruntime value--------larger value-->**

Each runnable task is placed in self balancing Red Black tree based on `vruntime`. If task is ready to run (means task is not waiting for any resource), It is placed to tree. If task is waiting for some resource (i.e waiting for I/O  )then it is removed. Tasks those have less processing time (means smaller `vruntime` ) are towards left side of tree and tasks having more processing time are right side of tree.

Left node has the smallest key value (For CFS ,it is task with higher priority). Self balancing red black tree need O(lgN) operation to navigate towards left node. Scheduler caches this value in `rb_leftmost`. By retrieving only this value ,scheduler determine which task to run next

This load balance is used for non real task only [for real time](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/real-time-linux-kernel-scheduler) task push-pull operations are used which is  developed by Steven Rostedt and Gregory Haskins

One more thing about CFS is also helpful in Fair Group Scheduling .Consider [below figure](http://criticalblue.com/news/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/linux_scheduler.pdf)

[image]

[`move_task`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c?v=3.14#L4980) is simply try to move up imbalance weighted load (means after calculating load factor as shown above ) from busies to `this_rq`. It try to equal the load balance of both run queue so that both can spare "fair" processor time.

`detach_task` detach the task for the migration specified in `env` pointer of linux kernel.

`detach_one_task` tries to dequeue exactly one task from env->src_rq.

[`detach_tasks()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L5702) tries to detach up to imbalance weighted load from
`busiest_rq`. And it  returns number of detached tasks or else zero if fail to detach.

To attach this detached task to new `rq`(run queue) , `attach_task, attach_one_task,attach_tasks` is used according to situation.

New warning check [`lockdep_assert_held()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/lockdep.h#L365) is introduced in `detach_tasks` which was not present in `move_tasks`

[On multi-processor it is not easy to move task so easily](https://lwn.net/Articles/80911/) so cfs do domain specific load-balancing as below:
[image]

For all this to understand I would like you to go through following reference

1. [Per-Entity-Load-Tracking metric for load balancing](https://lists.linaro.org/pipermail/linaro-dev/2012-November/014472.html)
2. [weight factor](https://oakbytes.wordpress.com/2012/07/03/linux-scheduler-cfs-and-virtual-run-time/)
3. [Open-suse](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE_121/opensuse-tuning/cha.tuning.taskscheduler.html)
4. [Robert-love Chapter 3](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101760)
5. [CPU-scheduling](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/6_CPU_Scheduling.html)

I specially read all these documentation to answer your question I hope you don't mind to comment if something is missing.

Comment: _task_h_load is used to calculate weight of task._ Read answer from this statement.If you still want me to point out something I would be happy to improve answer :-)

Comment: Hi, I agreed with him... the answer does not answer my real question but gives a lot of info from the surrounding...

Comment: Thank for comment @boaz So do you want to understand the pure code ? Is it okay for you if I would describe what h_load do so and so ..?

Comment: I actually shown What task_h_load do how Actually cfs works to calculate it That also I have shown.If you look into each and every link you can understand actually your question But though you point me out specific points I would love to improve answer.